# Javascript .test() & .exec() function inconsistent result?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

JS .test() & .exec() function produced inconsistent result, after execution the result flip.

while .match() still consistent

Is it because of the unicode ?

```js
const REGEX = /@([+]?[a-z]+)\u00AD/gm;
const text = `@test­`;

console.log('-------------------------------------------------------')
console.log(`REGEX.test(text) ${REGEX} ${text} ${REGEX.test(text)}`)
console.log(`REGEX.test(text) ${REGEX} ${text} ${REGEX.test(text)}`)
console.log(`REGEX.test(text) ${REGEX} ${text} ${REGEX.test(text)}`)
console.log(`REGEX.test(text) ${REGEX} ${text} ${REGEX.test(text)}`)
console.log('-------------------------------------------------------')
console.log(`REGEX.exec(text) ${REGEX} ${text}`, REGEX.exec(text))
console.log(`REGEX.exec(text) ${REGEX} ${text}`, REGEX.exec(text))
console.log(`REGEX.exec(text) ${REGEX} ${text}`, REGEX.exec(text))
console.log(`REGEX.exec(text) ${REGEX} ${text}`, REGEX.exec(text))
console.log('-------------------------------------------------------')
console.log(`text.match(REGEX) ${REGEX} ${text}`, text.match(REGEX))
console.log(`text.match(REGEX) ${REGEX} ${text}`, text.match(REGEX))
console.log(`text.match(REGEX) ${REGEX} ${text}`, text.match(REGEX))
console.log(`text.match(REGEX) ${REGEX} ${text}`, text.match(REGEX))
```

Comment: Hint: What does `/g` do?

Comment: Calling `.exec()` repeatedly with the `g` flag on your regex advances through the string to find additional matches.  `.test()` does not do that.  Remove the `g` flag and try that.

Comment: ahhhh I see, thank you for the hint, its solved now.